# OpenCV -> IplImage vs. Mat

Tags: c++

I'm absolute begginer with OpenCV. I've installed 2.4.10 version. I wrote this easy script, and it works:

```
#include "opencv\cv.h"
#include "opencv\ml.h"
#include "opencv\cxcore.h"
#include "opencv\highgui.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("C:/Users/Me/Desktop/photo.jpg", 0);
    cvNamedWindow("Example");
    cvShowImage("Example", img);
    cvReleaseImage(&img);
    cvDestroyWindow("Example");
    return 0;
}
```

But I'd like to avoid using pointers.
I tried to replace selected lines by this functions:

```
 Mat img = imread("C:/Users/Me/Desktop/photo.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);

if (img.empty()) 
{
    return -1;
}
namedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("MyWindow", img);
```

It failed:
The program '[4296] Project1.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

I have no idea why IplImage* works but Mat not? What's teh difference? Maybe I didn't enclose proper library?

Comment: #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>, and run in debug to get error code

Comment: I added:
`#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>'

Error is still the same. While debbuging b step I've notice that image had negative dimensions while passing this function:
`Mat img = imread("C:/Users/Me/Desktop/photo.jpg")`
- so it wasn't upload at all.

Comment: Yep, check if image is loaded as "!img.data", not using empty()

Comment: I tried and `img.data` has 0 rows and columns as parameters. So code exit in first `if`.
I have no ide why because path to the picture is exactly the same as in first example and it works there. There are no other errors as well.

Comment: When I turn on Module Messages it turned out there are two PDB files which cannot be open. 
`'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\opencv_core2410.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\opencv_highgui2410.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.`

I read in other topic it shouldn't be a problem though.

Comment: No, pdb are not an issue. Double check image path, or put image in project dir and load it just with the name